# django static files 404 errors

Tags: python, django, static

could not load any static file, and keep poping out 404 errors, i looked through some posts about staticfiles 404 errors, but not help.

My installed apps like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'articles',
'bootstrap3',
'django_markdown',
'jquery',
'javascript_settings',]
```

and others like

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_root')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_dirs'),
)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

got traceback

```
[10/Apr/2015 00:13:47]"GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[10/Apr/2015 00:13:47]"GET /static/js/carousel.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[10/Apr/2015 00:13:47]"GET /articles/offcanvas.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2333
10/Apr/2015 00:13:47]"GET /articles/10 HTTP/1.1" 200 7760
[10/Apr/2015 00:13:47]"GET /media/IMG_1061.JPG HTTP/1.1" 404 2324
[10/Apr/2015 00:13:47]"GET /media/IMG_1061.JPG HTTP/1.1" 404 2324
[10/Apr/2015 00:13:48]"GET /assets/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf?noCache=1428639228343 HTTP/1.1" 404 2382
[10/Apr/2015 00:14:16]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6315
[10/Apr/2015 00:14:16]"GET /offcanvas.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2306
[10/Apr/2015 00:14:16]"GET /assets/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf?noCache=1428639256192 HTTP/1.1" 404 2382
```

plaese help!

Comment: Those are media assets...not static assets. The static assets are loading just fine.

Comment: @rnevius right...images are not displayed...what should i edit..

Answer (score -1):

You have to serve the media files from webservers like apache, gunicorn, nginx.

You have to configure the url of your media in the configuration file of the respective server.

Take a look at this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files). It explains how to configure webserver to serve media files. django server is an application server and it is better to use webservers to serve the media